# Iterating a table rows while it's filtered

Tags: oracle-adf

I 'm trying to iterate through the rows in a table that has been filtered in a Fusion Application in ADF. This table was created from a DataControl. Normally I iterate through the view object associated with the table but if the request is made while the table is still filtered the view object only iterates through the filtered rows. This is the code that I have so far

```
public void SelectingAll() {

    DCBindingContainer dcb = (DCBindingContainer) evaluateEL("#{bindings}");
    DCIteratorBinding dciter =dcb.findIteratorBinding("DimEntidadView1Iterator");        
    ViewObject vo = dciter.getViewObject();

    Row row = vo.first();
    vo.reset();        

    while (row != null) {

        row.setAttribute("SelectEnt","true");
        row = vo.next();
    }

}
```

The problem is that if the method is executed while the table is still filtered the ViewObject only iterates for the filtered rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think iterators are made exactly for this job, you don't need to access the ViewObject, think for a moment, what if the table is not based in a ViewObject? You can do something like this without refering you backend implementation:

```
    public void SelectingAll() {
        DCBindingContainer dcb = (DCBindingContainer) evaluateEL("#{bindings}");
        DCIteratorBinding dciter =dcb.findIteratorBinding("DimEntidadView1Iterator"); 

        RowSetIterator rsi = dciter.getRowSetIterator();
        while (rsi.hasNext()) {
            Row r = rsi.next();
            .
            .
            .
        }
    }
```

Comment: I try this but still has the same problem, if the table is filtered de iterator only iterates through the filtered rows.

Comment: Now I understand, just add another view instance and iterator, with RangeSize = -1. if it doesn't solve you problem, explain exactly what you want to do.